C# JSON: I want to deserialize an empty string to a custom type. But it seems to be always defaulting to null. Is there a way to achieve this
I want JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomType>("") to be deserialized to new CustomType()
but this is always deserialized to null.
this is using Newtonsoft json, have tried using a custom readjson method but it does not work.

Does ?? and ??= operators - the null-coalescing operators help?

So why don't you just put a return string.IsNullOrEmpty(json) ? new CustomType() : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); around it?

An empty string is not valid JSON, let alone a valid JSON object. You're trying to convert the JSON into an object, so the best the JSON parser can do is give you null.
If you get an empty string as an input, turn it into {}, a JSON empty object, first.
string input = "";

if (input is "") // you could replace with "string.IsNullOrEmpty()", or other forms
{
    input = "{}";
}

CustomType data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomType>(input);
// data is not null

https://dotnetfiddle.net/njXmng
As mentioned by Gene, you could shortcut not doing the deserialization if your input is an empty string. This may improve performance if DeserializeObject is an expensive operation (please benchmark this yourself and balance it with readability and maintenance efforts).
string input = "";
CustomType data;

if (input is "") // you could replace with "string.IsNullOrEmpty()", or other forms
{
    data = new CustomType();
}
else
{
    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomType>(input);
}

As mentioned by Luke Vo, you could also do post-processing on the deserialization result (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomType>("") ?? new CustomType()), but I would prefer to correct the input value. This reduces the "garbage in, garbage out".

"While an empty string is a valid JSON value" - citation needed. For example, Javascript JSON.parse("") gives an error. A JSON empty string is still "" (2 characters)

In fact this question explains it correctly.

"While an empty string is not valid JSON two quotes is valid JSON", ah! got it.
